# Merge data sets based on group identifiers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data sets with 2 different type of observations. The observations were made during different days and they are recorded on different time intervals.

Both records have a serial number that is used to identify a group people who conducted observations. For example serial 111 denotes a group people. This group is formed by different number of people. The number of people belonging to these groups varies. For example group 111 consists of 3 people. In the diaries we can identify people belonging to different groups by `serial` and `id1` variable. For example `serial 111 and id1 2` means that the observation was made by person number two from the group 111. There is also a `Day` variable that denotes the week day when the observation was made. The `Day` variable takes values from `1(Monday) to 7 (Sunday)`.

If in `df1` we have 1 observation per person in `df2` each person had to conducted 2 observations. The person who made the observation can be identified based on `serial, id1 and id2`. `Id2` is used to make difference between the week day observations. For example id 111, id1 3 and id2 2 can be interpreted as the 2 day observation made by person number 2 from the group 111. The week day of the observation is similarly saved by the `Day` variable.

I want to identify those persons who recorded information on the same day in both diaries. So, who are those individuals who filled in both records on the same day. The problem is that in `df2` there are 2 observations and in `df1` just one per person and this makes merging difficult.

I merged based on `serial and id1` but they are not unique identifiers. I tried to create a new variable and to merge on 'Day' level.

How can I merge the 2 data sets on daily level?

```
library(dplyr)

df1<-df1 %>% 
      mutate(index = group_indices_(df1, .dots=c("serial", "id1"))) 

df2<-df2 %>% 
      mutate(index = group_indices_(df2, .dots=c("serial", "id1", "id2")))
```

Sample date:

df1

```
structure(list(serial = c(12, 123, 123, 10, 10), id1 = c(1, 1, 
2, 1, 2), Day = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

df2

```
structure(list(serial = c(12, 12, 123, 123, 123, 123, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10), id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
    id2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Day = c(1, 6, 
    3, 7, 2, 7, 4, 7, 2, 7, 4, 7), index = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Sample data outcome:

```
serial id1 id2 Day
12      1   1   1
123     1   1   3
123     2   1   2
10      1   1   4
10      2   1   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the corresponding `id2` value from `df2` to `df1` with an update-join using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, id2 := i.id2, on = .(serial, id1, Day)]

df1
#    serial id1 Day id2
# 1:     12   1   1   1
# 2:    123   1   3   1
# 3:    123   2   2   1
# 4:     10   1   4   1
# 5:     10   2   2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `merge` like below

```
merge(df1,df2,all.x = T)[1:4]
```

such that

```
> merge(df1,df2,all.x = T)[1:4]
  serial id1 Day id2
1     10   1   4   1
2     10   2   2   1
3     12   1   1   1
4    123   1   3   1
5    123   2   2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use merge:

`out <- merge(d1, d2, by = c('serial', 'id1'))`

and then select the columns serial, id1, id2, Day

Comment: many thanks I tried this and I received duplicate values for the missing id2  values

Comment: filter them with: out[ !is.na(out$id2), ]